# HTML Table structure not displaying data in right order

Tags: php, html, json, foreach, html-table

I have a table that displays data from JSON. I am able to display the data in the table but it does not render the table very well.

The structure of the table is distorted. It does not display the data in the order in which I want it to display.

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php 
        $url = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // path to your JSON file
        //$url = 'data.json'; // path to your JSON file
        $data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
        $characters = json_decode($data);
        $i = 0;
    ?>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <?php
            foreach ($characters as $character) 
            {
                ?>   
            <td>
                <?php echo $character->name; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $character->phoneNumber; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $character->amount; ?>
            </td>
            <?php }
        ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I expect three columns only. With the data showing in the right order

Comment: Hard to say without knowing 1: what the JSON looks like, 2: what the CSS looks like for the `table` and `table-bordered` classes and 3: whether you're using the [jQuery datatables](https://datatables.net/) plugin (guessing since the id is `dataTable`) - any of those things could break the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<?php 
            $url = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // path to your JSON file
            //$url = 'data.json'; // path to your JSON file
            $data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
            $characters = json_decode($data);
            $i = 0;
            ?>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            foreach ($characters as $character) 
            {
             ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $character->name; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $character->phoneNumber; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $character->amount; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php }
            ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why should they try this? What gave you changed and why?

Comment: @Dharman, Sorry for my poor English. I think they put <tr> outside foreach loop, when foreach run will create more than 3 <td> on only one <tr>...

Comment: You should explain your answer as best as you can. It doesn't need to be much, but at least one sentence to say what change you are suggesting. Don't tell people to try something. It sounds like you give an order. Teach them what mistake they have made.

Comment: I really want to do that, but my English is not enough. Sorry!

Comment: @shandonjoe I am so happy about that!